# how can I make equals predicate returns non case sensitive result in hazelcast values(Predicate arg0) function

Tags: java, predicate, hazelcast

Is there any way to make hazelcast values(Predicate arg0) function non-case sensitive.

I am trying to filter a IMap based on the name, but the values function search and returns only exact match(case sensitive data).

Comment: An overriden implementation of the values(Predicate arg0) method could be the solution.

Comment: String key="name"; 
String value="ShaRan";
final Predicate<String, Person> predicate = entryObject
     .get(key).equal(value);
personList = (ArrayList<Person>) personMapObject
     .values(predicate);

Comment: entryObject .get(key).equalsIgnoreCase(value), i think here is where you need to dig.

Comment: thank you. can you please guide me to override values(Predicate arg0)  function to return non case sensitive result, i am using  equal(value) method whole over my project so it will be easy to add a single function to fix the problem.